# What are the implications of choosing a Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

As far as I have seen when using a `Navigation Drawer (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)`, you have to use Fragments.

So All activities have to be transformed into fragments.

Furthermore all logic will now reside in the Activity of the `Navigation Drawer` so the size of the Activities file could be really large and not maintenance friendly.

Are there any other implications and is there an easier way of going about these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using a `NavigationDrawer` you *have* to use `Fragment`s.

- Not true. It is just as possible to have `Activity`s as well.
  `Fragment`s, though, are supposed to represent more modular &
  reusable UI blocks.

> All logic will now reside in the `Activity` of the `NavigationDrawer`
>   so the size of the `Activitiy` file could be really large and not
>   maintenance friendly.

- If you take a look at the [Google I/O
  app](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogle%2Fiosched&ei=xEbrVKTRBYiIuAStxYHoAQ&usg=AFQjCNH3ynQbpQaVXtE1T_wPxSosyYbK0Q&bvm=bv.86475890,d.c2E),
  what they have done is create a class `BaseActivity` that holds all
  common functionality (including the `NavigationDrawer`), and then all
  other `Activity`s are extended from that class. This way, all
  `Activity`s have many common features, along with `NavigationDrawer`,
  but without replicating large amounts of code.

> What are the implications of choosing a `NavigationDrawer` in Android?

- As the above two points note, it is possible to use `Activity`s
  **OR** `Fragment`s, and it is possible to encapsulate code within a resuable `BaseActivity`so that the same code is not rehashed
  everywhere. So the implication is certainly **not** that a
  `NavigationDrawer` *increases* the complexity of the code structure.
  The purpose of the `NavigationDrawer` is to simplify navigation that
  would otherwise be complex and tedious to manage, both for the user
  and programmer.

Comment: Wondering how to add it for multiple activities. Dont you have to add it in all the activities?

Comment: Inheritance is one way of avoiding that.

Comment: @Ranjith Create a `BaseActivity` that contains the navigation code then for all activities instead of inheriting / extending `Activity` rather extend `BaseActivity`

Comment: @StevieG Thanks..i never thought it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I made an app with that a while ago and I did not transform all activities into fragments but just a kind of a main menu, then when you engaged on some "different" activity you didnt have the drawer until you came back, it can even be annoying.

As for the logic I put some in the Fragments (the relevant to each fragment) for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to have a single activity is simple. It's because you want it to stay persistent.

If you had multiple activities, they'd all need to implement the same drawer layout, which would lead to you inflating and populating the drawer multiple times.

The activity just acts as a container for the fragments and the drawer layout. It acts like a bridge between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your concept wrong. Let me explain why.

> As far as I have seen when using a Navigation Drawer
>   (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout), you have to use Fragments.
>   So All activities have to be transformed into fragments.

That is wrong. You can use just activities, or fragments, or a mix, your choice.

The `DrawerLayout` is just a `ViewGroup`. Nothing more, nothing less. Just like `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` and many others. As defined by the official documentation:

> ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called
>   children.)

And that's exactly what the `DrawerLayout` is. A `ViewGroup` that exposes a "drawer like" interface that can be opened and closed with a swipe/drag gesture.

Said all that, several of the tutorials you'll find online use fragments just because they're a modular way of building UI components. But you can just as well use just normal views, like the example from the official guides:

Here you'll see a `ListView` to act as options for the navigation and a `FrameLayout` where the current "main content" will be placed inside.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**edit:** suggested abstract activity:

(all typed by heart, likely errors, just a general approach)

```
public abstract BaseActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances){
       super.onCreate(savedInstances);
       super.setContentView(R.layout.base_activity); // that's the layout above

      // do here the logic to setup the `ListView` and listen to OnItemClick for the list items

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void setContentView (int layoutResID){
      // here we override setContentView force content inside the FrameLayout
      LayoutInflater.from(this)
         .inflate(layoutResID,
                  findViewById(R.id.content_frame, true);
   }

   @Override
   public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        // here you navigate to a different activity
   }
}
```

Comment: 100% correct. But using activities with the DrawerLayout would mean you have to duplicate the layout and drawer navigation code on every activity you use. Which is not DRY.

Comment: That's a different topic. That's about software architecture and how you, as a developer, make it good. Two options (there are certainly others): 1) You can have 1 activity with the Drawer and drawer "content". And have one fragment for each `mainContent` The activity code is just the fragment switching and the each fragment have it's own code related to its own content. 2) You can have an `abstract` activity with the Drawer and each concrete activity just "implements" the content. Important is that nothing is forcing you to take certain approach.

Comment: Yet there is no suggested or best practice approach. I like the abstract activity approach but I need to research how to implement that. So for now I am implementing interchangeable fragments that implement `onClickListeners` so they can do logic.

Comment: the training guide I posted the link suggests option 1). And fragments were always meant to have the logic of the content they generate. I can suggest a quick skeleton for the abstract activity, I'll edit my answer, check again soon